# Number of 4-colorings of Johnson solids

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I want to know the number of 4-colorings for all [Johnson solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid). This is equivalent to evaluating the flow polynomial for the corresponding polyhedral graphs at $k=4$.

I tried the following to get the data:

```
Table[{i, 4 GraphData[{"JohnsonSkeleton", i}, "FlowPolynomial"][4]}, {i, 92}]
```

But for nos. 38-43, 47, 48, 68-82,

```
Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

is returned.

I have also tried, for example

```
FlowPolynomial[GraphData[{"JohnsonSkeleton", 38}], 4]
```

which causes Mathematica to hang.

Is there another way?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
As ilian pointed out in the comments, the command `FlowPolynomial` does in fact seem to work-the missing graph numbers just need a lot of memory and time to compute.

I tested the command on a machine with 32GB RAM to confirm ilian's value for $n=38$ (`500792391843`)and also got the value for $n=39$ (`500453836143`). But $n=40$ exhausted all the RAM and crashed the machine.

So maybe it's unrealistic to ask for the 4-colour numbers for all the Johnson graphs after all. In that case I'd be very happy to settle for approximations of the missing numbers.

**EDIT** I'm also interested in the same question for the Archimedean solids and their duals (Mathematica is also missing some data for these).

Comment: Have you tried asking Wolfram support? Is there any fundamental reason why there shouldn't be a value associated with those solids?

Comment: Not yet, I did try the `FlowPolynomial` command also but it makes my Mathematica freeze/crash.

Comment: @AthanasiosEvangelou You should definitely report the crash to Wolfram support.

Comment: @MarcoB I don't know any reason why these data should be missing.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, I meant to say hang instead of freeze. My PC is not the greatest so I'm not sure if it's a deficiency with my hardware--could you test the command `FlowPolynomial[GraphData[{"JohnsonSkeleton", 38}], 4]` on your system?

Comment: Yes, it hangs. After 10 minutes I shut it down. But I don't know what is a reasonable computation time for a graph like this ...

Comment: Might just be a long computation -- I got `500792391843` after 43 minutes and needed around 21 GB of memory.

Comment: @ilian Maybe this is missing from `GraphData` because it took too long to compute then?